# EXCEL SUMIF Returning Incorrect Values

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have an id column on 2 excel sheets. For ex, on one sheet A1 = 831250, A2 = 831251, A3 = 831252. On the other sheet, A1 = 250, A2 = 251, A3 = 252. As you can see, the first sheet has a prefix of 831 in the id column. I am using the formula below, however it is returning the same result for all, which is the total for all 3. Is this a bug, or is there an error in my formula? Weird thing is that VLOOKUP works.

=SUMIF('831 Summary'!$A:$A,"831" & Comparison!$A2,'831 Summary'!$F:$F)

Comment: If it is a text string issue, you could just wrap your `criteria` argument with the `VALUE()` function... `VALUE("831"&Comparison!$A2)`

Answer (score 2):

`"831" & Comparison!$A2` is creating a literal text string.  A text string does not equal a number.

Try `--("831" & Comparison!$A2)` instead.  It will convert the text string back to a number.

```
=SUMIF('831 Summary'!$A:$A,--("831" & Comparison!$A2),'831 Summary'!$F:$F)
```